# Docker & Django: Django is looking for a DB table before running migrations

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

When I run docker-compose, all containers start without errors except "`catering-django-1`". As I understand it, django looks for the "`myapp_menu`" table in the DB before running the migrations. However, everything works for me locally. That is, when I write "`python3 manage.py migrate`" in the console - everything works flawlessly. I can't figure out what the problem is for a long time and I hope for your help. Thank you!

**Docker-compose logs:**

```
Attaching to catering-django-1, catering-nginx-1, catering-postgres-1, catering-redis-1, catering-redis-commander-1, catering-worker-1
catering-redis-1            | 1:C 26 Aug 2023 17:55:06.942 # WARNING Memory overcommit must be enabled! Without it, a background save or replication may fail under low memory condition. Being disabled, it can also cause failures without low memory condition, see https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/issues/1328. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
catering-redis-1            | 1:C 26 Aug 2023 17:55:06.942 * oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
catering-redis-1            | 1:C 26 Aug 2023 17:55:06.942 * Redis version=7.2.0, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
catering-redis-1            | 1:C 26 Aug 2023 17:55:06.942 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
catering-redis-1            | 1:M 26 Aug 2023 17:55:06.942 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
catering-redis-1            | 1:M 26 Aug 2023 17:55:06.942 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
catering-redis-1            | 1:M 26 Aug 2023 17:55:06.943 * Server initialized
catering-redis-1            | 1:M 26 Aug 2023 17:55:06.943 * Loading RDB produced by version 7.2.0
catering-redis-1            | 1:M 26 Aug 2023 17:55:06.943 * RDB age 213 seconds
catering-redis-1            | 1:M 26 Aug 2023 17:55:06.943 * RDB memory usage when created 0.92 Mb
catering-redis-1            | 1:M 26 Aug 2023 17:55:06.943 * Done loading RDB, keys loaded: 0, keys expired: 0.
catering-redis-1            | 1:M 26 Aug 2023 17:55:06.943 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
catering-redis-1            | 1:M 26 Aug 2023 17:55:06.943 * Ready to accept connections tcp
catering-postgres-1         | 
catering-postgres-1         | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
catering-postgres-1         | 
catering-postgres-1         | 2023-08-26 17:55:06.979 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.4 (Debian 15.4-1.pgdg120+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
catering-postgres-1         | 2023-08-26 17:55:06.979 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
catering-postgres-1         | 2023-08-26 17:55:06.979 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
catering-postgres-1         | 2023-08-26 17:55:06.990 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
catering-postgres-1         | 2023-08-26 17:55:07.006 UTC [29] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-08-26 17:51:46 UTC
catering-postgres-1         | 2023-08-26 17:55:07.022 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
catering-redis-commander-1  | Creating custom redis-commander config '/redis-commander/config/local-production.json'.
catering-redis-commander-1  | Parsing 1 REDIS_HOSTS into custom redis-commander config '/redis-commander/config/local-production.json'.
catering-redis-commander-1  | node ./bin/redis-commander  
catering-redis-commander-1  | Using scan instead of keys
catering-redis-commander-1  | No Save: false
catering-redis-commander-1  | listening on 0.0.0.0:8081
catering-redis-commander-1  | access with browser at http://127.0.0.1:8081
catering-redis-commander-1  | Redis Connection redis:6379 using Redis DB #0
catering-worker-1 exited with code 0
catering-nginx-1            | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
catering-nginx-1            | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
catering-nginx-1            | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
catering-nginx-1            | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
catering-nginx-1            | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version
catering-nginx-1            | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
catering-nginx-1            | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
catering-nginx-1            | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
catering-postgres-1         | 2023-08-26 17:55:09.036 UTC [33] ERROR:  relation "myapp_menu" does not exist at character 41
catering-postgres-1         | 2023-08-26 17:55:09.036 UTC [33] STATEMENT:  SELECT "myapp_menu"."first_course" FROM "myapp_menu"
catering-django-1           | Traceback (most recent call last):
catering-django-1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
catering-django-1           |     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
catering-django-1           |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
catering-django-1           | psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "myapp_menu" does not exist
catering-django-1           | LINE 1: SELECT "myapp_menu"."first_course" FROM "myapp_menu"
catering-django-1           |                                                 ^
catering-django-1           | 
catering-django-1           | 
catering-django-1           | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
catering-django-1           | 
catering-django-1           | Traceback (most recent call last):
catering-django-1           |   File "/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
catering-django-1           |     main()
catering-django-1           |   File "/app/manage.py", line 18, in main
catering-django-1           |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
catering-django-1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
catering-django-1           |     utility.execute()
catering-django-1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
catering-django-1           |     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
catering-django-1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
catering-django-1           |     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
catering-django-1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 448, in execute
catering-django-1           |     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
catering-django-1           |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
catering-django-1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 96, in wrapped
catering-django-1           |     res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
catering-django-1           |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
catering-django-1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 97, in handle
catering-django-1           |     self.check(databases=[database])
catering-django-1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 475, in check
catering-django-1           |     all_issues = checks.run_checks(
catering-django-1           |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
catering-django-1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
catering-django-1           |     new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
catering-django-1           |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
catering-django-1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
catering-django-1           |     return check_resolver(resolver)
catering-django-1           |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
catering-django-1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
catering-django-1           |     return check_method()
catering-django-1           |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
catering-django-1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 494, in check
catering-django-1           |     for pattern in self.url_patterns:
catering-django-1           |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
catering-django-1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
catering-django-1           |     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
catering-django-1           |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
catering-django-1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 715, in url_patterns
catering-django-1           |     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
catering-django-1           |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
catering-django-1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
catering-django-1           |     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
catering-django-1           |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
catering-django-1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 708, in urlconf_module
catering-django-1           |     return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
catering-django-1           |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
catering-django-1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
catering-django-1           |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
catering-django-1           |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
catering-django-1           |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
catering-django-1           |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
catering-django-1           |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
catering-django-1           |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
catering-django-1           |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
catering-django-1           |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
catering-django-1           |   File "/app/mysite/urls.py", line 26, in <module>
catering-django-1           |     path('', include('myapp.urls')),
catering-django-1           |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
catering-django-1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 38, in include
catering-django-1           |     urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
catering-django-1           |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
catering-django-1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
catering-django-1           |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
catering-django-1           |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
catering-django-1           |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
catering-django-1           |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
catering-django-1           |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
catering-django-1           |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
catering-django-1           |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
catering-django-1           |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
catering-django-1           |   File "/app/myapp/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
catering-django-1           |     from .views import \
catering-django-1           |   File "/app/myapp/views.py", line 13, in <module>
catering-django-1           |     from .forms import ProfileUpdateForm, AddMenuForm, OrderForm
catering-django-1           |   File "/app/myapp/forms.py", line 98, in <module>
catering-django-1           |     class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
catering-django-1           |   File "/app/myapp/forms.py", line 99, in OrderForm
catering-django-1           |     first_course = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[("", 'Select a dish')] + [(f"{item}", item) for item in list(
catering-django-1           |                                                                                                       ^^^^^
catering-django-1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 394, in __iter__
catering-django-1           |     self._fetch_all()
catering-django-1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1867, in _fetch_all
catering-django-1           |     self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
catering-django-1           |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
catering-django-1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 281, in __iter__
catering-django-1           |     for row in compiler.results_iter(
catering-django-1           |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
catering-django-1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1349, in results_iter
catering-django-1           |     results = self.execute_sql(
catering-django-1           |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
catering-django-1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1398, in execute_sql
catering-django-1           |     cursor.execute(sql, params)
catering-django-1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 102, in execute
catering-django-1           |     return super().execute(sql, params)
catering-django-1           |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
catering-django-1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
catering-django-1           |     return self._execute_with_wrappers(
catering-django-1           |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
catering-django-1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
catering-django-1           |     return executor(sql, params, many, context)
catering-django-1           |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
catering-django-1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
catering-django-1           |     with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
catering-django-1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
catering-django-1           |     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
catering-django-1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
catering-django-1           |     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
catering-django-1           |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
catering-django-1           | django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "myapp_menu" does not exist
catering-django-1           | LINE 1: SELECT "myapp_menu"."first_course" FROM "myapp_menu"
catering-django-1           |                                                 ^
catering-django-1           | 
catering-django-1           | Waiting for postgres ready...
catering-postgres-1         | 2023-08-26 17:55:09.552 UTC [34] ERROR:  relation "myapp_menu" does not exist at character 41
catering-postgres-1         | 2023-08-26 17:55:09.552 UTC [34] STATEMENT:  SELECT "myapp_menu"."first_course" FROM "myapp_menu"
catering-django-1           | Traceback (most recent call last):
catering-django-1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
catering-django-1           |     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
catering-django-1           |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
catering-django-1           | psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "myapp_menu" does not exist
catering-django-1           | LINE 1: SELECT "myapp_menu"."first_course" FROM "myapp_menu"
catering-django-1           |                                                 ^
```

My project tree:

```
.
├── docker-compose.yaml
├── docker-entrypoint.sh
├── Dockerfile
├── __init__.py
├── manage.py
├── media
    ...
├── myapp
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── fixtures
│   │   └── myapp
│   │       └── menu.json
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tasks.py
│   ├── templatetags
│   │   ├── custom_filters.py
│   |   └── __init__.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── mysite
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings
│   │   ├── base.py
│   │   ├── celery.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── local.example.py
│   │   ├── local.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── nginx
│   ├── conf.d
│   └── Dockerfile
├── poetry.lock
├── pyproject.toml
├── pytest.ini
├── README.md
├── static
│   ├── admin
        ...
│   ├── myapp
        ...
│   └── userauth
        ...
├── templates
│   ├── admin
        ...
│   ├── base.html
│   ├── myapp
        ...
│   └── userauth
        ...
├── tests
    ...
└── userauth
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── forms.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── migrations
    │   ├── 0001_initial.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.py
```

My `docker-compose.yaml:`

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
        restart: unless-stopped
        image: postgres:15
        env_file:
          - .env
        volumes:
          - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
        networks:
          - bobik300_network
  django:
        restart: unless-stopped
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        env_file:
          - .env
        volumes:
          - static_volume:/app/static
          - media_volume:/app/media
        networks:
          - bobik300_network
        depends_on:
          - postgres

  nginx:
        restart: unless-stopped
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: ./nginx/Dockerfile
        ports:
          - "80:80"
        volumes:
          - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
          - static_volume:/app/static
          - media_volume:/app/media
        networks:
          - bobik300_network
        depends_on:
          - django
  redis:
        image: redis:latest
        command: redis-server
        volumes:
          - redis:/var/lib/redis
          - redis-config:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
        ports:
          - 6379:6379
        networks:
          - bobik300_network

  redis-commander:
        image: rediscommander/redis-commander:latest
        env_file:
          - ./.env
        ports:
          - 8081:8081
        networks:
          - bobik300_network
        depends_on:
          - redis
  worker:
        image: python:3.11
        env_file:
          - ./.env
        volumes:
          - ./:/app/
        depends_on:
          - redis
volumes:
    static_volume:
    media_volume:
    postgres_data:
    redis:
    redis-config:
networks:
  bobik300_network:
    driver: bridge
```

My `Dockerfile:`

```
FROM python:3.11 
    

ENV PYTHONBUFFERED=1 \
    POETRY_VERSION=1.5.1 \
    POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_CREATE="false"
    
RUN pip install "poetry==$POETRY_VERSION"

    
WORKDIR /app

  
COPY pyproject.toml docker-entrypoint.sh ./

    
RUN poetry install --no-interaction --no-ansi --only main --no-root

    
COPY . .
    
EXPOSE 8000
    
RUN chmod +x docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

My `docker-entrypoint.sh:`

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
until cd /app
do
    echo "Wait for server volume..."
done


until python manage.py migrate 
do
    echo "Waiting for postgres ready..."
done


python manage.py collectstatic  --noinput

python manage.py loaddata menu.json

gunicorn mysite.wsgi:app --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 4 --threads 4

celery -A mysite.settings.celery worker -l info
```

My `.env:`

```
DB_PORT=5432
DB_HOST=catering-postgres-1 # <- the name of container
POSTGRES_DB=postgres
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
```

My `base.py:`

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages'
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.forms',
    'myapp',
    'userauth',
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_DB'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': os.environ.get('DB_POST'),
    }
}


...

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "userauth.CustomUser"

MEDIA_ROOT = 'media/'
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
STATIC_ROOT = "static/"
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"

FIXTURE_DIRS = [
    'myapp/fixtures/myapp/',
]

...
```

My `nginx/Dockerfile:`

```
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

My `conf.d:`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name catering_django_1 ;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://catering_django_1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    }

    location static { alias /app/static/; }

    location media { alias /app/media/; }

}
```

I hope that all the above information will help you better understand my problem. I also tried stopping postgresql locally (sudo service postgresql stop), deleting all docker images, containers and volumes, but it didn't help. Help me please (((

Answer (score 0):

You do not really check if postgres is up with the following lines:

```
until python manage.py migrate 
do
    echo "Waiting for postgres ready..."
done
```

You simply echoing a string and do nothing more (same for echo "Wait for server volume..."). Following my proposal to wait with the migrations until postgres is up and running:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

postgres_ready() {
    python << END
import sys

from psycopg2 import connect
from psycopg2.errors import OperationalError

try:
    connect(
        dbname="${POSTGRES_DB}",
        user="${POSTGRES_USER}",
        password="${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}",
        host="${POSTGRES_HOST}",
        port="${POSTGRES_PORT}",
    )
except OperationalError:
    sys.exit(-1)
END
}

until postgres_ready
do
  >&2 echo "Waiting for PostgreSQL to become available..."
  sleep 2
done
>&2 echo "PostgreSQL is available"

cd /app
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py collectstatic  --noinput

python manage.py loaddata menu.json

gunicorn mysite.wsgi:app --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 4 --threads 4

celery -A mysite.settings.celery worker -l info
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried your approach and I got this error in the logs (I think it can't connect to the DB) - "host not found in upstream "catering_django_1" ". Then I tried to change the server name in conf.d from "catering-django-1" to "django" and as a result I got just "Waiting for PostgreSQL to become available...". I ended up making the following changes to the dockerentrypoint.sh file "connect(dbname=os.environ.get("POSTGRES_DB"), etc using os.environ.get())" and got the same error as in my question "psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "myapp_menu" does not exist".

Comment: Just use `postgres` as db host in your environment variables, not `catering_django_1`.